# Attaching Xcode debugger to Xamarin app running in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, xamarin

I have a Xamarin iOS app and I would like to inspect the view hierarchy using the Xcode View UI Hierarchy tool. I tried to follow this: [Debugging Xamarin.IOS apps with Xcode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/debugging-with-xcode), but the Xcode debugger just would not attach to the running app.

Any other suggestions for how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

After some trial and failure, I was able to attach to my Xamarin iOS app running in iOS simulator:

- Run your app in an iOS simulator, e.g. run from Visual Studio
- In XCode,

  - Open any iOS project, e.g. create a dummy iOS project
  - Select the same simulator as your app is running on as the target for deploy
  - In Debug -> Attach to Process by PID or Name... type the name of your app, e.g. MyApp.iOS, and Attach

Voila!